# Invert pairs of neighboring digits

Tags: shell, unix, awk

How can I invert in a file all pairs of neighboring digits?

Example input:

```
a3972b
```

Output:

```
a9327b
```

I tried to use  : `awk`

`awk { $1 | rev }`

but it does not work, could you tell me how to invert only numbers 2 by 2

Comment: What does this have to do with C or C++?

Comment: *I tried to use : awk* - and what happened?

Comment: I tried `awk` too, and it worked for me.

Comment: doesn't work  awk  { $1 | rev }  idk how to  invert only numbers 2 by 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `sed` [back-references](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html):

```
echo a3972b c5981b | sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\)\([[:digit:]]\)/\2\1/g'
```

Output:

```
a9327b c9518b
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a `awk` solution: (gawk)

You can use the following command:

```
$ echo a3972b u1234v | awk '{print gensub(/([0-9])([0-9])/,"\\2\\1","g",$0)}'                                                   
a9327b u2143v
```

for details about `gensub` have a look at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html